# bind event to create_image

Tags: python, button, canvas, tkinter

I discovered that in Tkinter there is a limit to the maximum canvas size available: [SO:tkinter maximum canvas size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830037/tkinter-maximum-canvas-size/42837629#42837629)

BUT this limit his hit when placing stuff by grid (I dont know about `pack` or `place`): a counterexample by *Sun Bear* shows that `cv.create_image` is unaffected.

The problem is that the images I want to show have to be bound to a mouseclick - that's the reason I was `grid`-ding buttons. The question is, can I create by this function something similar to a button, able at least to respond to Button-1 ?

From [infohost](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_image.html) I see that `cv.create_image` returns the integer ID number of the image object - can I use it to bind to it?

Comment: _" I want to show have to be bound to a mouseclick - that's the reason I was grid-ding buttons"_ - that statement makes no sense. The use of `grid` has no bearing on bindings.

Comment: I didnt explain me well - I want to show a lot of images, and I want them to react to B1.  The easiest way (for me) was to grid a lot of buttons, each one displaying one image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From infohost I see that cv.create_image returns the integer ID number of the image object - can I use it to bind to it?

Yes, this is a documented feature. You can use the `tag_bind` method:

```
image_id = canvas.create_image(x, y, image=the_image)
canvas.tag_bind(image_id, "<1>", clickHandler)
```