# tkinter canvas - checkbutton list is incomplete

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.checkbutton

when building a checkbutton list (3,000 cases) the list is cut off.

Here is a small sample:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw",
                                  tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        self.populate()

    def populate(self):

        for row in range(3000):

            t="Example -Checkbutton %s" %row
            button = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, padx=7, relief=tk.RIDGE, text=t,                                    
                                onvalue=1, offvalue=0,  font='Courier 12')
            button.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky='news')
            
    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    example = Example(root)
    example.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

**The output of the program:**

| | Example checklist 0

---

| | Example checklist 1123

---

| | Example checklist 1126

---

| | Example checklist 1125

---

---

| | Example checklist 2999

The example checklists 1126 - 2998 are not displayed and the example checklist 2999 is indicated by a double line.

**Is there a parameter that shows the complete list?**

Comment: Canvas with <configure> can usually handle nearly 10-10^2  small elements at a normal rate (without any delays). Are you okay with 3*10^3 check buttons? It was slow from my side

Comment: @RahulARanger: I don't think you really meant `10-10^2`. That's -90.

Comment: It seems like there is limitation on `create_window()`, see [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830037/tkinter-maximum-canvas-size).

Comment: @BryanOakley I think RahulARanger means 10 to 10^2.

Comment: @BryanOakley 10 to 10^2

Comment: Rahual: with 3*10^3 check buttons is exactly what I need. I know, the build of the list is slow, but it solves the problem. 
 What is your solution for that problem?

Comment: The canvas isn't unlimited in size. You're probably hitting the limit.

Comment: @Eddi instead of scrollbar use something like < > arrows to navigate between frames (each frame has 20-30 check buttons) (u can use JSON file to store the values)