# python tk tkinter multiple widgets is out of my scrollable frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,  NavigationToolbar2Tk) 
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from data import dataprocess
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1500x800')
container = tk.Frame(root)
main_canvas = tk.Canvas(container, width=1480, height=800,  bg='blue')
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=main_canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(main_canvas, bg='black')

scrollable_frame.bind(
"<Configure>",
lambda e: main_canvas.configure(
    scrollregion=main_canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)

main_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

main_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

for i in range(1400):
    btn = tk.Button(scrollable_frame, text='btn' + str(i)).grid(row=i, column=0)

container.grid()
main_canvas.grid()
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=7, sticky="nse")
[enter image description here][1]container.mainloop()
```

My buttons can not show inside the frame, seems like my frame can not afford that much widgets.
Is there any method to fix it?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgZGh.png

Comment: There seems to be size limitation on frame, max. 32768x32768.  See [tkinter-maximum-canvas-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830037/tkinter-maximum-canvas-size).

Comment: I would like to display multiple images in the main canvas. Is there any suggestion that can deal with this limitation.

Comment: You can use `create_image(...)` directly.