# Python Tkinter Scrollbar and Frame not showing all Checkboxes

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox, scrollbar, frame

having an issue with some tkinter code and I believe I am just too close to it and can't see the issue in front of my face. I am loading checkboxes into a frame and attaching a scrollbar to that location.

This works well until I get to a little over 1000 checkboxes. It then seems to cut off and even though the frame extends a height appropriate for all checkboxes it is not showing them in the gui. You can see in the image here where they stop showing [Checkbox Malfunction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcb7Q.png)

Here is my code: (Please excuse how messy it looks, it is a subset of a much larger code set, I've just isolated the error)

```
from tkinter import *


build_vars = {}
build_Radios = []
parent = Tk()

center_container = Frame(parent, width=5, height=5)
center_container.grid(row=1, sticky="nsew")

# Center Row Columns
center_center_container = Frame(center_container, width=150, height=200)
center_center_container.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ns")

build_canvas = Canvas(center_center_container, background='green')
build_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+E+W+S)

# Create a vertical scrollbar linked to the canvas.
vsbar = Scrollbar(center_center_container, orient=VERTICAL, command=build_canvas.yview)
vsbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)
build_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsbar.set)

# Create a frame on the canvas to contain the buttons.
frame_buttons = Frame(build_canvas, bd=2, background='red')

def create_build_radios():

    # for index, item in enumerate(filtered_builds):
    for index, item in enumerate(list(range(3000))):
        build_vars[item] = IntVar()
        radio = Checkbutton(frame_buttons, text=item, variable=build_vars[item], onvalue=1,
                        offvalue=0,
                        command=lambda item=item: sel(item))
        radio.grid(row=index, column=0, sticky=W)
        build_Radios.append(radio)

    # Create canvas window to hold the buttons_frame.
    build_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame_buttons, anchor=NW)
    build_canvas.update_idletasks()  # Needed to make bbox info available.
    bbox = build_canvas.bbox(ALL)  # Get bounding box of canvas with Buttons.
    build_canvas.configure(scrollregion=bbox, width=150, height=400)

def sel(item):
    print(item)

create_build_radios()
parent.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't know why, my checkbox list stop at 1310. but your sample code, this two line seems need intent:

radio.grid(row=index, column=0, sticky=W)
build_Radios.append(radio)

Comment: @moogoo thanks! Was a copy and paste issue with Stackoverflow not accepting my formatting. This has been fixed.

Comment: The canvas has limits to how much it can display. You're probably hitting that limit.

Comment: Can you expand on this? The canvas height seems to expand, it is why I have colored it. What do you mean by it has limits to what it can show? Also, if this is a solution, please put it in the solutions section.

Comment: EDIT: I reread that answer and it seems that there still is some limitation Maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830037/tkinter-maximum-canvas-size, the basic idea in your case would be to create windows and place them at coordinates and pass the checkbutton widget as windows

Comment: @buzzard0190 Why do you need 3000 `Checkbutton`s? You should be able to display more if you put them in a grid?

Comment: @TheLizzard the client has specific needs, 3000 represents the actual data points they have access to.  Would love for you to expand in the solutions section if you have an idea.  Thanks!!

Comment: @buzzard0190 I think that @ BryanOakley's comment makes sense. That is why I suggested putting the `Checkbutton`s in a grid. If you make 4 columns of `Checkbutton`s, you should be able to fit all of the 3000 without glitches.

Comment: @buzzard0190 I was trying to overengineer the solution but then I remembered that you could try using simple pagination, basically have multiple canvas to switch between and limit the widgets per canvas

Comment: @Matiiss That will still take a long time to code if OP wants a smooth transitioning between canvases. Also I was looking forward to your solution :(.

Comment: @TheLizzard I meant like literal pagination, you have a choice of pages and you can click on say 3 and go to the third page and stuff, well my idea has a slight issue which is that it is not possible to know the height of widget until it is put on screen which makes the whole process pretty hard (tho I thought of a few solutions so I will get back to coding)

Comment: @Matiiss What about moving the frame that's inside the canvas instead of scrolling the canvas? That isn't going to take that much work. As the problem with that canvas is when the `y>50000`, if we never scroll the canvas the problem should be solved.

Comment: @TheLizzard I tried, but it capped at about 1500 (I was also packing labels) (back to the drawing board)

Comment: @Matiiss I spent 1h trying to program it an it capped at 1559 labels for me too. This is very frustrating. I created a canvas that directly communicates with the scrollbar. Also my computer becomes very laggy when I try to display that many labels.

Comment: @TheLizzard I managed to get my idea working so you can check it out (not really done yet but has the basic funcitonality: can add a lot of widgets and  scroll through all of them (currently only by dragging the slider))

Answer (score 1):

So here is the better solution (way better than the other, can easily put way more widgets on this, tho note that there probably is some kind of limit (at least the CPU's capabilities):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, Label, Scrollbar, Button, DoubleVar, StringVar, Entry
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar


class PagedScrollFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, items_per_page=100, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self.items_per_page = items_per_page
        self.pages = None
        self.id_list = []
        self.bbox_tag = 'all'

        self._loading_frame = Frame(self)
        self.__load_progress_tracker = DoubleVar(master=self.master, value=0.0)
        self.__percent_tracker = StringVar(master=self.master, value='0.00%')

        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack(side='top', padx=20, pady=20)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame)
        self.canvas.pack(side='left')

        self.bg_label = Label(self.canvas)
        self.bg_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.frame, orient='vertical', command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>',
                         lambda e: self.canvas.config(
                             scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(self.bbox_tag)
                         ))

        self.button_frame = Frame(self)
        self.button_frame.pack(fill='x', side='bottom', padx=20, pady=20)

        self.canvas_frame = Frame(self.button_frame)
        self.button_canvas = Canvas(self.canvas_frame, height=20)
        self.button_canvas.pack(expand=True)
        self.inner_frame = Frame(self.button_canvas)
        self.button_canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.inner_frame, anchor='nw')

        self.button_scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.canvas_frame,
                                          orient='horizontal',
                                          command=self.button_canvas.xview)
        self.button_scrollbar.pack(fill='x')
        self.button_canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.button_scrollbar.set)
        self.button_canvas.bind(
            '<Configure>', lambda e: self.button_canvas.config(
                scrollregion=self.button_canvas.bbox('all')
            )
        )

    def pack_items(self):
        if not self.pages:
            return
        self._loading_frame.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self._loading_frame.lift()
        self._loading_frame.update_idletasks()
        self.after(100, self._pack_items)

    def _pack_items(self):
        Label(self._loading_frame, text='Loading...').pack(expand=True)
        Progressbar(self._loading_frame,
                    orient='horizontal',
                    variable=self.__load_progress_tracker,
                    length=self._loading_frame.winfo_width()
                           - self._loading_frame.winfo_width() // 10).pack(expand=True)
        Label(self._loading_frame, textvariable=self.__percent_tracker).pack(expand=True)
        self.update_idletasks()
        widgets = [widget for page in self.pages for widget in page.winfo_children()]
        length = len(widgets)
        self.after(100, self.__pack_items, widgets, 0, length)

    def __pack_items(self, widgets, index, length):
        if index >= length:
            self._loading_frame.destroy()
            self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))
            return
        widgets[index].pack()
        percent = (index + 1) * 100 / length
        self.__load_progress_tracker.set(value=percent)
        self.__percent_tracker.set(value=f'{percent: .2f}%')
        self.after(1, self.__pack_items, widgets, index + 1, length)

    def change_frame(self, index):
        if not self.pages:
            return
        self.bbox_tag = self.id_list[index]
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(self.bbox_tag))
        self.bg_label.lift()
        self.pages[index].lift()

    def create_pages(self, num_of_items, items_per_page=None):
        self.pages = None
        if not items_per_page:
            items_per_page = self.items_per_page
        num_of_pages = num_of_items // items_per_page
        if num_of_items % items_per_page != 0:
            num_of_pages += 1
        start_indexes = [items_per_page * page_num for page_num in range(num_of_pages)]
        end_indexes = [num + items_per_page for num in start_indexes]
        end_indexes[-1] += (num_of_items % items_per_page
                            - (items_per_page if num_of_items % items_per_page != 0 else 0))
        self.pages = [Frame(self.canvas) for _ in range(num_of_pages)]
        self.id_list = []
        for page, frame in enumerate(self.pages):
            self.id_list.append(self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=frame, anchor='nw'))
        self.pages[0].lift()
        if num_of_pages >= 2:
            Button(self.button_frame, text='1',
                   command=lambda: self.change_frame(0)).pack(
                side='left', expand=True, fill='both', ipadx=5
            )
            if num_of_pages > 2:
                self.canvas_frame.pack(fill='x', expand=True, side='left')
                for page_num in range(1, num_of_pages - 1):
                    Button(self.inner_frame, text=page_num + 1,
                           command=lambda index=page_num: self.change_frame(index)).pack(
                        expand=True, fill='both', side='left', ipadx=5
                    )
            Button(self.button_frame, text=num_of_pages,
                   command=lambda: self.change_frame(num_of_pages - 1)).pack(
                side='right', fill='both', expand=True, ipadx=5
            )
        return zip(start_indexes, end_indexes, self.pages)


def create_paged_canvas():
    scroll = PagedScrollFrame(root)
    scroll.pack()

    lst = tuple(range(3000))
    for start, end, parent in scroll.create_pages(len(lst)):
        for i in lst[start:end]:
            frame_ = Frame(parent)
            Label(frame_, text=str(i).zfill(4)).pack(side='left')

    scroll.pack_items()


root = Tk()
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', exit)

create_paged_canvas()

root.mainloop()
```

**Main info:**
Basically this creates paged scrollable canvas. All that is needed is to adjust the inner loop and the iterable in the `create_paged_canvas()` function. You can also adjust how many items per page to show (that also allows for later configuration for example in a menu you could call a similar to `create_paged_canvas()` function and change the `items_per_page` argument to sth else (will have to load everything again but... `tkinter` is `tkinter`, it is pretty slow and even worse it doesn't allow directly using threads, not even talking about processes (that stuff would speed things up very much but simply can't be done)))

**Important** (suggestion):
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

**Misc:**
for better performance it would be better to instead of creating labels simply create text directly on canvas (using the other solution) or use a listbox, that is in case if you need to display huge amounts of data because it will speed things up since no widgets have to be created (it also means you can only view the data pretty much)

If you have any questions, be sure to ask those!

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the solution:

**Very Important**
There is some bizzare bug that I have no idea how to fix (yet at least) regarding performance and stuff, which makes this solution pretty unusable, I mean theoretically you will be able to put more widgets on this and scroll than the usual method but depending on the CPU it may work or it may not work that well. I will simply write a pagination answer

```py
from tkinter import (Tk, Frame, Label, Scrollbar, Canvas,
                     DoubleVar, Entry, Button, StringVar, TclError)
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar


class EndlessScroll(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, update_mode='passive', scrollbar=None, **kwargs):
        """update_mode:
                        'passive' (recommended and default): widgets have to be accessed (Text, Entry...)
                                  or using Frame, DON'T use if only single widget per line,
                                  USE Frame with this
                        'active': recommended only if single widget
                                  per line (best with Label
                                            but can use Button too)"""
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self._widget_heights = []
        self._start_index = 0
        self._widgets = []
        self.temp_frame = None
        self.__got_height = False
        self.__initialised_placement = False
        self.__height_counter = 0
        self.yscrollincrement = None
        self._update_mode = update_mode
        self.scrollbar = scrollbar
        self.__load_progress_tracker = DoubleVar(master=self.master, value=0.0)
        self.__percent_tracker = StringVar(master=self.master, value='0.0%')
        self._allow_mouse_control = False
        self.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: setattr(self, '_allow_mouse_control', True))
        self.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: setattr(self, '_allow_mouse_control', False))
        self.bind('<MouseWheel>', self.__scroll_with_mouse)
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    def __scroll_with_mouse(self, event):
        if not self._allow_mouse_control:
            return
        self.yscroll('scroll', (-1 * (event.delta/120)), 'units')

    def set_scrollbar(self, scrollbar):
        self.scrollbar = scrollbar

    def init_after_widgets(self):
        self.temp_frame = Frame(self)
        self._widgets = self.winfo_children()[:-1]
        self.temp_frame.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.update()
        Label(self.temp_frame, text='Loading...').pack(expand=True)
        Progressbar(self.temp_frame,
                    orient='horizontal',
                    variable=self.__load_progress_tracker,
                    length=self.temp_frame.winfo_width()
                           - self.temp_frame.winfo_width() // 10).pack(expand=True)
        Label(self.temp_frame, textvariable=self.__percent_tracker).pack(expand=True)
        self.after(100, self._get_widget_heights, 0)

    def _get_widget_heights(self, index):
        length = len(self._widgets)
        self.after(100, self.__get_widget_heights, index, self._widgets, length)

    def __get_widget_heights(self, index, widgets, length):
        if index >= length:
            self.__got_height = True
            self.temp_frame.place_forget()
            self._initial_placement(widgets)
            self.update_idletasks()
            self.__update()
            self.yscroll(None, 0)
            return
        id_ = self.create_window(0, 0, window=widgets[index], anchor='nw')
        self.update()
        try:
            self._widget_heights.append(widgets[index].winfo_height())
            self.delete(id_)
        except TclError:
            pass
        percent = (index + 1) * 100 / length
        self.__load_progress_tracker.set(value=percent)
        self.__percent_tracker.set(value=f'{percent: .2f}%')
        self.after(1, self.__get_widget_heights, index + 1, widgets, length)

    def yscroll(self, *args):
        if not self.__initialised_placement or not self.scrollbar:
            return
        type_, fraction = args[0], args[1]
        parent_height = self.winfo_height()
        if type_ == 'scroll':
            units = args[2]
            k = float(fraction)
            if k < -1.0:
                k = -1.0
            elif k > 1.0:
                k = 1.0
            top, bottom, *_ = self.scrollbar.get()
            length = (bottom - top) if not self.yscrollincrement else self.yscrollincrement
            if (top == 0.0 and k < 0) or (bottom == 1.0 and k > 0):
                return
            if 0 < top < length:
                length = top
            if 0 < (1 - bottom) < length:
                length = 1 - bottom
            if units == 'units':
                fraction = top + (k * length)
            elif units == 'pages':
                return
                # fraction = top + (k * (0.9 * parent_height) * length)
        sum_height = sum(self._widget_heights)
        scroll_height = float(fraction) * sum_height
        height_counter = 0
        for index_, height in enumerate(self._widget_heights):
            height_counter += height
            if height_counter > scroll_height:
                self._start_index = index_
                self.__height_counter = -(height - (height_counter - scroll_height))
                break
        self.scrollbar.set(float(fraction), float(fraction) + parent_height / sum_height)
        if self._update_mode == 'passive':
            self.__update()

    def __update(self, _call_from_self=False):
        if _call_from_self and self._update_mode == 'passive':
            self.after(10, self.__update, True)
            return
        parent_height = self.winfo_height()
        height_counter = self.__height_counter
        self.delete('all')
        for height, widget in zip(self._widget_heights[self._start_index:], self._widgets[self._start_index:]):
            if height_counter > parent_height:
                break
            self.create_window(0, height_counter, window=widget, anchor='nw')
            height_counter += height
        self.after(10, self.__update, True)

    def _initial_placement(self, widgets):
        parent_height = self.winfo_height()
        height_counter = 0
        for height, widget in zip(self._widget_heights, widgets):
            if height_counter > parent_height:
                self.__initialised_placement = True
                return
            self.create_window(0, height_counter, window=widget, anchor='nw')
            height_counter += height


def create_scroller():
    endless_scroll = EndlessScroll(root, yscrollincrement=0.1)
    endless_scroll.pack(side='left')

    for i in range(100):
        frame = Frame(endless_scroll)
        Label(frame, text=str(i).zfill(4)).pack()

    scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, command=endless_scroll.yscroll)
    scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

    endless_scroll.set_scrollbar(scrollbar)
    endless_scroll.init_after_widgets()


root = Tk()

create_scroller()

root.mainloop()
```

**MAIN_EDIT:**
I polished the widget a bit, rest of the instructions are still valid, but I fixed the below issue with having a widget so that you can see the last widget added (was an index problem), now you can see all of them. Added mouse scrolling and scrolling with the scrollbar's arrows (still can't move it by clicking on scrollbar, no idea how to do that either (yet)). Also now shows percentage, reduced some waiting time. Also now it catches the error which gets raised if you close the window while loading is in progress.
Basically you just have to go to the `create_scroller()` function definition and adjust the loop for your needs.

**Important** (suggestion)
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

---

The main instruction here is that you have to place the `.init_after_widgets()` method after you have added widgets to the `EndlessScroll` widget (don't pack the or anything just add them (as you can see in the example)). <strike>Note the special widget, will try to fix that too so that it works properly and also very important is that it currently only works with dragging the slider of the scrollbar (will fix that too (at least try)).</strike>

The thing is that it now works, it can theoretically show any number of widgets (tried with 50000 but that was very laggy and I had to close it but with the 3000 it worked like a charm), also great thing is that the window is responsive while "loading" the widgets (loading is necessary for getting the height of the widgets which is crucial) so yeah, you can try improving this yourself but I will also try doing that myself too but a bit later.

EDIT1:
For example if you wanted to have more widgets together you can use frames:

```py
for i in range(100):
    frame = Frame(endless_scroll)
    Label(frame, text=f'Entry {i}:').pack(side='left')
    Entry(frame).pack(side='right')
```

Solved this to an extent. See edit below.
<strike>Tho this specific example has a slight issue with the entries because of the `.__update()` loop, otherwise widgets that are static should work completely fine (Buttons have less of an issue but it might be harder to press them, Entry and Text widgets are probably unusable)</strike>

EDIT2:
added option to change update mode to deal with the above mentioned problem (read docstring in the `EndlessScroll` class). The issue is using Frame, it basically breaks the now "active" mode loop (probably because of amount of data) so with it you have to use "passive" mode however that means less smooth updates (also "passive" mode horribly updates if you don't use a Frame). So you can also use "active" mode but only when you have one widget per line (hopefully this will be solved by @TheLizzard by making some kind of custom `.grid()` method or sth, **in comments**) and then it updates very smoothly. So currently unless there really is a need to have a lot of widgets in a column and have them extend to other columns, I would suggest using the usual methods of adding scrolling. That is of course unless you are fine with a little bit of flickering when dragging the slider, other methods don't produce that issue.

If you have any questions, ask them!

Comment: Nice solution but I want to add support for all geometry managers. I will bookmark this and try thinking of an answer that works with all geometry managers.

Comment: @TheLizzard to which part do you want to add this support? the `EndlessScroll` widget or widgets that are put into it? the `EndlessScroll` widget already has support for all geometry managers (at least it should since it simply inherits from Canvas). The widgets inside? they don't even use a geometry manager, they are placed using `.create_window` method of canvas, I guess you could try replacing that with `.place()` but other managers? those will require some other container. But it is possible to put frames inside the `EndlessScroll` and then use any geometry manager on those frames

Comment: I know that you used `.create_window`. The problem is that doesn't help if you want to make a form that the user has to fill in with labels on the left and entries on the right. I want to make a more general solution. I should have a working prototype by the end of today (unless I get lazy :D).

Comment: @TheLizzard umm... you can simply use a frame, edited the post to include an example of the form you mentioned tho there is a slight issue that has to be fixed: updating

Comment: Also wouldn't there be alignment problems? If one label is shorter than the others. I have already programmed the `grid` geometry manager from scratch so it shouldn't be too difficult to add it the canvas.

Comment: @TheLizzard I edited answer to include some additions but I am really looking forward to your grid method since I think it will solve the Frame performance issue because a frame won't be needed (read EDIT2)

Comment: I made a prototype. The code is [here](https://pastebin.com/0G27N801). But it's very slow when creating the widgets. It has no support for scrollbars (only mouse wheel support). Half of the code is from another [project](https://github.com/TheLizzard/tkpygame) so the code is quite unreadable. I am not going to be updating it.

Comment: @TheLizzard I kind of finished, it is pretty horrible at the end maybe a different approach should be used to creating widgets on canvas, for example not deleting anything but simply changing coords or sth like that, basically I will simply write a pagination answer which shouldn't have this issue

Comment: I think the only easy solution is not to have 3000 widgets in a column but make it 4 columns. That way it you wouldn't hit the y-limit on the canvas.

Comment: @TheLizzard I made the pagination solution in case you wanted to check out