# Python Tkinter:Frames are not going under each otheer

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I was making a simple tkinter GUI which has scrolling frames in it but it is not being so perfect for me.At first I used only one frame, but however I found out that frames have a limit on the no. of widgets they can hold,so I started using multiple frames. However I got this problem:the frames are not going in the direction I wanted.I wanted the frames to go under the previous frame ,however the frames are going one above the other here is a screenshot of the same:
[image]

(Frame 0 is the first Frame)

Here is the code(I have only kept the important portion)

```
i=0
image_no=0
for video in videos:
    
    u = urllib.request.urlopen(video["thumbnail"]["thumbnails"][0]["url"])
    raw_data = u.read()
    u.close()

    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.resize((470,210)))
    a.append(image)

    tk.Label(fr[i], image=a[image_no]).pack()
    image_no+=1
    tk.Label(fr[i], text=("Video:"+str(image_no)+" frame:"+str(i)),wraplength=470,font=("ariel",11,"bold"),bg="white").pack()
    tk.Label(fr[i], text=video["title"]["accessibility"]["accessibilityData"]['label'].replace(video["title"]["runs"][0]["text"],""),wraplength=470,font=("ariel",10),bg="white",fg="grey").pack(anchor="w")
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)

    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
    print(image_no)
    print(video["title"]["runs"][0]["text"])
    if image_no%10==0:
        time.sleep(3)
    if image_no%110==0:
        i+=1
    if image_no%440==0:
        break
```

Is there any way I could make it go downwards?

**Edit:**

Here is the screenshot of the frame limit

[image]

the black area is of the canvas

Comment: AFAIK, `pack` places from from top to bottom based on availability of the position. Also how are you making the frames. If you use `append` to add them to `fr`, then the last appended item will be the last in the list. Wild guess: Try `fr[::-1][i]` instead of `fr[i]`.

Comment: ok will try to do so

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: _"I found out that frames have a limit on the no. of widgets they can hold"_ - how did you come to that conclusion? If there are limits, it's measure in the tens of thousands or more.

Comment: @CoolCloud: it's not so much top-to-bottom, but rather it allocates space along one side, as determined by the arguments. By default it's top-to-bottom but it could also be bottom-to-top, left-to-right, right-to-left, or any other combination.

Comment: @BryanOakley I found out after image no 124 onwards was not shown in the frame if I kept all the widgets in one frame.

Comment: That is not a limit on the number of widgets in a frame, that's a limit on the size of an object (as measured by the number of pixels) that a canvas can show. A canvas doesn't have an infinite size.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ah yes, was just talking about the default case

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68730103/python-tkinter-scrollbar-and-frame-not-showing-all-checkboxes/68747811#68747811?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to question  [tkinter maximum canvas size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830037/tkinter-maximum-canvas-size)

I've modified the code due to the possibility that the number of images may be responsible or the canvas may have some maximum height.

This will now fill the entire canvas height with images, each with a 10 point space between.

I've updated it for python 3.x and increased height to 100000!

Works without problems.

Choose your own image (gif or png)

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fido

root = tk.Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

picture = fido.askopenfilename(title = "Pick a pic")

iconimage = tk.PhotoImage(file = picture)
wide, high = iconimage.width(), iconimage.height()

frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, labelanchor = "s", text = "0|0")
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

cv = tk.Canvas(
    frame, width = 1200, height = 700,
    scrollregion = "0 0 2000 100000")
cv.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(
    frame, orient = "vertical", command = cv.yview)
vscrollbar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "ns")
cv.config(yscrollcommand = vscrollbar.set)

def rowcol(ev):
    frame["text"] = f"{cv.canvasx(ev.x)} | {cv.canvasy(ev.y)}"

cv.bind("<Motion>", rowcol)
root.update()

testimage = []
for pos in range( 0, 100000 - high - 10, high + 10):
     testimage.append(cv.create_image(100, pos, anchor = "nw", image = iconimage))

print(f"Number of images = {len(testimage)}, width = {wide}, height = {high}")

root.mainloop()
```

So it doesn't seem to be a limitation of `Canvas` height or number of images displayed.

Comment: it is working alright,but there is a lot of space b/w the image and the scroll bar

Comment: how do i remove it without affecting the images as when I tried to  change the width and height ,the images are only shown partially

Comment: You can modify the x position of image by changing `cv.create_image(100,` to appropriate value. Canvas width is set to 1200 by 700 so change that to suit, also `scrollregion` can be modified to suit the maximum image width.

Comment: Good one @Code2D, happy coding.