# Scrollbar of my app is working not correctly when content is large what must I do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, infinite-scroll

```
from tkinter import *

#Root
root = Tk()
root.title('A WINDOW')

#Frame
main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = True)

#Canvas
main_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
main_canvas.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand = True)

#Scrollbar
scrollbar = Scrollbar(main_frame, orient = VERTICAL, command =  main_canvas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = 'y')

#Configure the Canvas
main_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

#Frame@2
Frame2 = Frame(main_canvas)
main_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window = Frame2, anchor = 'nw')
main_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e :main_canvas.configure(scrollregion=main_canvas.bbox('all')))
for i in range(2000):
    Button(Frame2, text = str(i)).grid(row = i, column = 0)



root.mainloop()
```

**and when I execute the program, it works until the 1080th one then scrollbar moves but buttons don't go down anymore I hope you understood me and have an idea about what must I do...**

Comment: The canvas isn't infinitely long. You're probably hitting its limit. I know there's at least one other question on this site that is asking the same thing.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830037/tkinter-maximum-canvas-size

Comment: For me it is not 1080 but 185

Comment: Bind `<Configure>` on `Frame2` instead of `main_canvas`

Comment: @acw1668 it didn't work actually can not you post a line to me?

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for your help but to be honest I must try to fix it up :D

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria First of all thanks for your help and if you're able to post your code with us it'd help us for real!

Comment: A maximum height of 32768 is due to the canvas window object. If you make your buttons small enough (small font, zero padding and borderwidth) it's possible to squeeze them all onto the canvas. I've used 2000 canvases of height = 14 and they are all visible.

Comment: so there is no way to put 2000 buttons with height = 30, right?

Comment: That's correct but the limitation is only confined to each canvas window item created. So distribute buttons in multiple window items and stack them end to end.

Comment: Hey then may I ask you a question? can we do an app which will do : it'll write buttons up till the 1000th one then automatically get to the other window do you know anything about it? by the way, I saw your answer but to be honest it didn't help me that much but I have to thank you besides. If you answer my question it makes me feel good, have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight modification of your code. It demonstrates the limitation of the window object in `tk.Canvas` with a maximum height of 32768. It can be shown by changing variable `offset` to some arbitrary value and scrolling to the end of canvas. The last button will still be visible even though its position is 32768+offset.

Function `bookmark` finds `frame2` in the window object and finds all objects in `frame2` then changes background color. This makes it easy to confirm first and last buttons are visible.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, labelanchor = tk.S, text = '0|0')
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)
for a in [root, frame]:
    a.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    a.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

main_canvas = tk.Canvas(frame)
main_canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient = tk.VERTICAL, command =  main_canvas.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.NS)
main_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)

def location(event):
    x, y = main_canvas.canvasx(event.x), main_canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    frame['text'] = f'{x} | {y}'

# bind mouse
main_canvas.bind('<Motion>', location)

frame2 = tk.Frame(main_canvas)
# frame is positioned at offset
offset = 0
main_canvas.create_window(0, offset, window = frame2, anchor = tk.NW)

def bookends(x):
    # Find reference to frame2
    C = main_canvas.winfo_children()[0]
    # find all objects in frame2
    D = C.winfo_children()
    print(len(D))
    # change colors of first and last buttons
    D[0]['background'] = 'red'
    D[x]['background'] = 'red'

for i in range(2000):
    tk.Button(
        frame2,
        text = str(i),
        font = '{Courier New} 6',
        padx=0, pady=0).grid(
            row = i, column = 0, ipadx = 0, ipady = 0)

bookends(1999)

# main_canvas['scrollregion'] = f'0 0 40 {32768+offset}'
main_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e :main_canvas.configure(scrollregion=main_canvas.bbox('all')))

root.mainloop()
```