# What is causing my canvas to cut off displayed images in the scrollable grid?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a simple Python GUI program..
It loads images from a folder and shows them in a scrollable grid. The problem I have is that it cuts off at some point.
Images are still there (I can select them with arrow keys), but are not visible. I can scroll with a scroll bar, but it gets to a position where a visible frame is cut off in the middle of the row and rest of the grid is hidden.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

# Function to load and resize the images
def load_and_resize_images(folder_path, size):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
            image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
            image = Image.open(image_path)
            image = image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            images.append(image)
    return images

# Create the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Scrollable Image Grid")
window.geometry("600x400")  # Adjust the window size as needed

# Set the folder path and image size
folder_path = "output"  # Change this to the path of your "output" folder
image_size = (100, 100)  # Change this to the desired image size

# Load and resize the images
images = load_and_resize_images(folder_path, image_size)

# Create a canvas to display the image grid
canvas = tk.Canvas(window)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Create a scrollbar for the canvas
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(window, command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

# Configure the canvas to use the scrollbar
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

# Create a frame inside the canvas to hold the image grid
frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor=tk.NW)

# Function to display the image grid
def display_image_grid():
    row = 0
    col = 0
    for image in images:
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        label = tk.Label(frame, image=img)
        label.image = img  # Keep a reference to prevent garbage collection
        label.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=5, pady=5)
        col += 1
        if col == 5:
            col = 0
            row += 1

# Call the function to display the image grid
display_image_grid()

# Configure the canvas scrolling
canvas.update_idletasks()
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

# Start the GUI event loop
window.mainloop()
```

Here's how it looks:
[image]

As you can see the scroll bar has still a lot of space to cover and I can move it to the far bottom - scrolling "nothing".

What am I missing here?

Comment: I suspect you're hitting the ±32767 limit to the coordinate system Tkinter uses.  There's nothing you can do to change that limit - but it might be possible to instead use a fixed grid of images that fills the window.  Nothing would actually scroll, you'd just change which images are being shown on the grid so that it *looks* like scrolling.

Comment: @jasonharper that's news to me, mind to share the source you got this information from?

Comment: @Thingamabobs: It's come up here a few times before, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70900157/scrollbar-of-my-app-is-working-not-correctly-when-content-is-large-what-must-i-d for example.

Comment: @jasonharper that is interesting. Couldn't find any limitations besides for [DecomposeMaskToShiftAndBits](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/main/generic/tkCanvas.c#L2499). So I don't think it is a direct limitation of the `Canvas`, more a general limitation on `PhotoImage`.

Answer (score 0):

As @jasonharper suggested, the issue seems to be related to Tkinter's limitation.

I have "solved" the problem by limiting the number of images displayed on the canvas to a 5x5 grid, creating an index of image sets, and allowing users to navigate between those sets.
This needs a proper pagination, but to make it simple, I have used left and right arrow keys to navigate between sets.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

MINIATURE_SIZE = (200, 200)
OUTPUT_FOLDER = "output"
IMAGE_SET_SIZE = 25  # Number of images in each set

image_sets = []  # List of image sets
current_image_set_index = 0  # Index of the currently loaded image set


def load_image_set(image_set_index):
    # Clear existing grid
    for child in image_grid.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()

    # Get the image set based on the index
    image_set = image_sets[image_set_index]

    # Create a grid of miniature images
    for i, image_file in enumerate(image_set):
        row = i // 5
        column = i % 5

        # Create a frame for each image
        frame = tk.Frame(image_grid, padx=5, pady=5)
        frame.grid(row=row, column=column)

        # Load and display the image
        img_path = os.path.join(OUTPUT_FOLDER, image_file)
        img = Image.open(img_path)
        img = img.resize(MINIATURE_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        image_label = tk.Label(frame, image=img_tk)
        image_label.pack()

        # Store the image filename in the label
        image_label.image_filename = os.path.splitext(image_file)[0]

        # Update the image label to make the border visible
        image_label.configure(bg=frame["bg"])

        # Keep a reference to the image to prevent garbage collection
        image_label.image = img_tk


def on_right_arrow_key(event):
    global current_image_set_index
    current_image_set_index = (current_image_set_index + 1) % len(image_sets)
    load_image_set(current_image_set_index)


def on_left_arrow_key(event):
    global current_image_set_index
    current_image_set_index = (current_image_set_index - 1) % len(image_sets)
    load_image_set(current_image_set_index)

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Miniature Image Grid")
root.geometry("1070x1070")

# Create the grid container
image_grid = tk.Frame(root)
image_grid.pack()

# Get all image files from the "output" folder
image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(OUTPUT_FOLDER) if f.endswith(".jpg")]

# Split the image files into sets of 25 images each
for i in range(0, len(image_files), IMAGE_SET_SIZE):
    image_set = image_files[i:i+IMAGE_SET_SIZE]
    image_sets.append(image_set)

# Load the initial image set
load_image_set(current_image_set_index)

# Bind arrow key events
root.bind("<Right>", on_right_arrow_key)
root.bind("<Left>", on_left_arrow_key)

# Start the main event loop
root.mainloop()
```

The best solution would be to calculate the needed canvas space (based on the total number of images, display size, border, spacing, etc.) and then add pagination if/when necessary.