Elements in scrollable frame below certain offset aren't rendered in TkInter
I'm using a canvas with a scrollable frame, but elements below a certain scroll offset aren't rendered. Here is an example app demonstrating that behavior. It contains 100 resizable squares in a long list, and a slider on top to set the sidelength. Above ca. 318 pixels sidelength, the lowest boxes aren't rendered anymore -- which hints at a 32,767 px limitation, even though the scrollbar works correctly (I can scroll into the unrendered space).
Is there any fix for that? How can I get a long scrollable element in Python?
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Canvas, Frame, Scrollbar, Scale

class ScrollableDemoApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("Scrollable Canvas Demo with Resizable Boxes")
        root.geometry("500x600")

        # Slider to control the size of the boxes
        self.box_size = 100  # Default size for the boxes
        self.size_slider = Scale(root, from_=100, to=1000, orient="horizontal", label="Box Size", command=self.resize_boxes)
        self.size_slider.set(self.box_size)
        self.size_slider.pack(fill="x", padx=10, pady=5)

        # Create a Canvas widget with a vertical scrollbar
        self.canvas = Canvas(root)
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        # Create a frame inside the canvas
        self.scrollable_frame = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

        # Add 100 boxes to the scrollable frame
        self.boxes = []
        for i in range(100):
            box = Frame(self.scrollable_frame, bg="white", highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1, 
                        width=self.box_size, height=self.box_size)
            box.pack_propagate(False)  # Prevent the frame from resizing to fit its contents
            box.pack(pady=5)

            # Add a label to display the index number in each box
            label = tk.Label(box, text=f"Box {i + 1}")
            label.pack(expand=True)

            # Store the box reference for resizing
            self.boxes.append(box)

        # Update the scroll region to encompass all the content in the scrollable frame
        self.scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))

    def resize_boxes(self, size):
        # Update box size based on the slider value
        self.box_size = int(size)
        for box in self.boxes:
            box.config(width=self.box_size, height=self.box_size)

        # Update the scroll region to ensure proper scrolling after resizing
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = ScrollableDemoApp(root)
    root.mainloop()


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830037/tkinter-maximum-canvas-size -- It's not the canvas, it's the scrollable frame... so placing elements directly on the canvas would probably work.

@OysterShucker No, ChatGPT is wrong there. The canvas does not have such a limitation, and I actually got it to work by placing everything directly on the canvas. The Frame is the thing which has this limit.

It was successful for me. Utilizing Python 3.12.7 for programming.
